# Did Kobna Holdbrook-Smith use the wrong voice, at one point, in Lies Sleeping?

Tags: audio-book, rivers-of-london

In *Lies Sleeping* the text of the book says:

> "We're not being casual," said Dr Vaughan. "This is a post mortem, not a dissection."

But the voice Kobna uses in the audiobook, at 4hr 26 minutes is of Dr Walid (who is also attending the post mortem).

Is that a mistake on Kobna's behalf, or was it changed partway through (from Walid to Vaughan, and he's remembering a read of a previous draft)?

Comment: *"Boy, I really hope that somebody got fired for that blunder [chortle, snort]"*